# add absolute path option to a command

Tags: shell-script

Given a shell command (let us call it "oldcommand"), is there a simple shell script newcommand.sh which will behave as oldcommand except that it will have a new "-location" option, and for example,

```
  newcommand -location path -nonfileoption1 x1 -fileoption2 x2 -fileoption3 x3  -nonfileoption4 x4
```

will execute

```
 oldcommand  -nonfileoption1 x1 -fileoption2 path/x2 -fileoption3 path/x3  -nonfileoption4 x4
```

Comment: How should `newcommand` know which arguments of `oldcommand` needed prefixing with `path`? You would have to write `newcommand` yourself (or get someone to write it for you).

Comment: @roaima see Thomas Dickey's answer. Obviously we assume that we have at our disposal a (reasonably short) list of all the available options for `oldcommand` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This smells a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you want `oldcommand` to treat all relative file names as relative to a different directory, change the current directory!

```
(cd path && oldcommand  -nonfileoption1 x1 -fileoption2 x2 -fileoption3 x3  -nonfileoption4 x4)
```

The parentheses ensure that the directory change is local: the next command will be executed in the original directory.

If you want to package this in a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$1" && shift && "$@"
```

Usage:

```
run-in path oldcommand  -nonfileoption1 x1 -fileoption2 x2 -fileoption3 x3  -nonfileoption4 x4
```

For command line usage, though, a temporary directory change might be more convenient. It requires a smidgen more typing, but it allows filename completion to work out of the box. (You can make completion work for the wrapper script method, but you'll need to define a completion function for the `run-in` script.)

```
cd path
oldcommand  -nonfileoption1 x1 -fileoption2 x2 -fileoption3 x3  -nonfileoption4 x4
cd -
```

or

```
pushd path
oldcommand  -nonfileoption1 x1 -fileoption2 x2 -fileoption3 x3  -nonfileoption4 x4
popd
```

Compared to what you're asking, this makes all relative file names relative to `path`, not just the ones passed on the command line but any relative file name that `oldcommand` uses internally. This also assumes that `oldcommand` doesn't itself change to a different directory. Both assumptions are met by many commands.

Comment: You have a point. The assumption is also met by the example I was needing it for. Now I feel a little guilty for having somewhat wasted the other answerers' time.

Answer (score 4):

If all you care about is an option at the beginning, that's a couple of lines of script.  Parsing the option in an arbitrary place and passing it to the `oldcommand` requires several lines and some knowledge of which options have values, and which do not.

For the *simple* case,

```
#!/bin/sh
[ "$#" -gt 2 && "x$1" = "x-location" ] && cd $2 && shift 2 && exec oldcommand "$@"
newcommand "$@"
```

For the complicated case, this sounds like something that you could do with `getopt` (not portable).  Further reading:

- [Using getopts in bash shell script to get long and short command line options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402377/using-getopts-in-bash-shell-script-to-get-long-and-short-command-line-options)
- [How can I use long options with the Bash getopts builtin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022592/how-can-i-use-long-options-with-the-bash-getopts-builtin)

Per discussion with OP, here is the pattern which may be used to simplify the problem: options beginning with "`-fileopt" should have the location option's value prepended.  So (no real error checking, and not *really* handling embedded special characters in the pathnames):

```
#!/bin/sh
PREP=
if [ "$#" -gt 2 ]
then
    PREP="$2/"
    shift 2
    ARGS=
    while [ "$#" != 0 ]
    do
        case "x$1" in
        (x-fileopt*)
            ARGS="$ARGS $1 ${PREP}$2"
            shift 2
            ;;
        (*)
            ARGS="$ARGS $1"
            shift 1
        esac
    done
    oldcommand $ARGS
else
    oldcommand "$@"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I clarify that I do not want to cd during the execution, and I am interested in what you call the "hard" case . You say that the hard case is doable, could you point a reference/link to some code snippets doing similar jobs that might be a starting point for me ?

Comment: How is the value for the `-location` option used?

Comment: I thought I had already made that clear in my OP. The -location option is an absolute path, prepended to all the filename-type options of the command.

Comment: I see - the pattern did not leap out at me.  I'll suggest something for that.

Comment: If `"-fileoption"` is not literally that, of course, the number of cases can get large (which was what I commented on initially).

Comment: And you fear that a large number of cases will raise performance problems ? In the situation I'm needing it, my oldcommand is something resembling gcc, with something like 7 options.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
opt()
    case ${1##*:*}:${#2} in
    (--:*) ! x=$((x-2))  ;;
    (-nonfileoption:[!0]*) p=;;
    (-fileoption:[!0]*)    p=\$2/;;
    (*:0)  eval $"{$x"':?Bad option::arg: "$1::$2"}';;
    (*)    eval $"{$((x-1))"':?Bad option: "$1"}'
    esac

[ " -location" = " $1" ] && x=2 parm= &&
while  [ "$#" -ge "$((x+=2))" ]
do     eval 'opt  "${'"$((x-1))"'}" "${'"$x}\"" ||
          until [ "$x" -eq "$#" ] && break 2
          do    parm=$parm' "${'$((x+=1))}\"
          done
       parm=$parm' "${'$((x-1))'}"  "'$p\${$x}\"
done&& eval "set -- $parm"
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It'll take some time for me to decipher it ...

Comment: @EwanDelanoy - any luck?

Comment: Currently I cannot parse `case $1:$2 in` (the only syntax I know is
`case $myvariable in`) and `(-fileoption:?"${2#?}")`

Comment: @EwanDelanoy - `case` syntax isnt necessarily `case $var in ...` its `case word in ...`. a shell *`word`* is one or more concatenated strings. like `'string1'\''string3'` where the backslash escaped `'` apostrophe is string2 - but all three make one *word*. and so `$1:$2` is just `case valueof$1:valueof$2 in` all strung together. the `(-option:?"${2#?}")` pattern matches `-option` to `$1` and the `:` to `:` and `?` and `"${2#?}"` for a not-null `"$2"`, see?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy - its way better now. is it any easier to get?

Comment: You forgot to initialize your variables in your new version, didn't you ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy - i only use `$x`, `$p` and `$parm`. `$p` is initialized for every `opt()` call, and `$x` and `$parm` are both initlalized if `$1 == -location`. i tried to take some pains to report any args/option error with detail - it will print the arg number and and its value to stderr for any unhandled  argument. that was to make it easier to debug and do more than just `-{non,}fileoption`